# Play video when is visible on vue

Tags: vue.js

I want to have a video start playing when it's visible, so I am trying to trace if it's visible with the following with no luck. The watch does not work.

```
<script>
  const inViewport = require('vue-in-viewport-mixin');

  export default {
    mixins: [ inViewport ],
    watch: {
     'inViewport.now': (newValue) => {
      console.log('test')
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch try using deep watcher